# UITextFields should get active in reverse order

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have six UITextFields one after another which is used for typing passcode.
after one character, next UITextFields becomes active. But how to do for backspace? On keyboard backspace, text field should get active in reverse order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your requirement, I made a demo and it is working like a charm.
So in order to fulfill your requirement you have to follow below instructions:

Give tag to every UITextField in order like 101,102,103,104,105 and 106

Then make every textField's delegate to self (UIViewController)

Then implement UITextField's below delegate method

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        print("string = \(string) text = \(textField.text)")

        if(textField.text?.characters.count == 1){

            if string.characters.count == 0{


                if textField.tag != 101{
                    textField.resignFirstResponder()

                    let preField : UITextField = self.view.viewWithTag(textField.tag-1) as! UITextField
                    preField.becomeFirstResponder()
                }

                textField.text = string
                return false
            }


            if textField.tag != 106{
                textField.resignFirstResponder()

                let nextField : UITextField = self.view.viewWithTag(textField.tag+1) as! UITextField

                nextField.text = string
                nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            }

            return false
        }

        return true
    }
```